# I am having problems with the app when leaving Wi-Fi and connecting to cellular via mobile router on a samsung tablet

Tags: applications, wi-fi

I am using a Samsung tablet for an application to manage a fleet of transportation vans. Inside the van we have a wireless router (Pepwave), when in the parking lot the Pepwave has priority to connect to the yards access point. This is to upload any surveillance video needed from the van.  I am trying to get rid of the data plan on the tablet and run off of the data plan on the Pepwave via Wi-Fi entirely.  It works great... for the most part.  The problem I am having is that when leaving the yard the Pepwave switches from Wi-Fi to cellular when the Access point is out of range.  The application does not refresh when this data provider transfer takes place.  All other apps like YouTube or internet browser for fine after connection reestablishes. The only solution so far is to toggle the Wi-Fi on the tablet on and off. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an automation assistant such as *Tasker* or *Automate*.

You can set these to detect the WiFi change of state and then toggle your tablet's WiFi setting off then on automatically.

It may only be a workaround for the problem but it may be the simplest fix.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a shot.